# Añadir Filtro a Buscador Dinamico JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, buscador

tengo este buscador que la funcion que hace es buscar en todas las columnas de mi Base de Datos la palabra que escribes. Pero quiero añadirle un Filtro por ejemplo que el Fabricante X, y que lo que escribas solo muestre lo que el Filtro/Condicion, en este caso seria mostrar de la palabra X solo con el FAbricante seleccionado, no se si me expliqué bien.

Dejo el codigo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<title>Buscador</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<link href="assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   (function($) {
       $('#FiltrarContenido').keyup(function () {
            var ValorBusqueda = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.BusquedaRapida tr').hide();
             $('.BusquedaRapida tr').filter(function () {
                return ValorBusqueda.test($(this).text());
              }).show();
                })
      }(jQuery));
});



</script> 
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Bienvenido</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           
            
                  
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
<?php include('table.css'); ?>
    <!-- Begin page content -->

<div class="container">
 <h1 class="mt-5">Buscador</h1>
 <hr>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["option"])){?>
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <strong>Hecho!</strong> El registro ha sido guardado con exito.
</div>
<?php }?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">

   <!-- Contenido -->    
   

<div class="input-group mb-4">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Buscar</span>
  </div>

  <input id="FiltrarContenido" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." aria-label="Alumno" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

</div>
     <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre Lagrima</th>
                <th>Fabricante</th>
                 <th>Formato</th>
                <th>Principio Activo</th>
                <th>Conservantes</th>
                <th>Composicion</th>
                <th>#</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="BusquedaRapida">
<?php
include "db.php";
$con = connect();
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM proyecto";


$resultado = mysqli_query($con , $consulta);
$contador=0;

while($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ $contador++;?>
<tr>
  
    <td data-label="Nombre LA"><?php echo $misdatos["nombre_la"]; ?></td>
      <td data-label="Fabricante"><?php echo $misdatos["fabricante"]; ?></td>

  <td data-label="Formato"><?php echo $misdatos["formato"]; ?></td>
  <td data-label="PA"><?php echo $misdatos["pa"]; ?></td>
  <td data-label="Conservante"><?php echo $misdatos["conservante"]; ?></td>
  <td data-label="Componente"><?php echo $misdatos["componente"]; ?></td>
  <td data-label="Ver Producto"><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $misdatos['id']; ?>"><div class='fa-2x' style="color:green"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> </div></a></td>
  </tr>
          
<?php }?>          

</tbody>
      </table>  
<!-- Fin Contenido --> 
</div>



</div><!-- Fin row -->


</div><!-- Fin container -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted"><p>Creado <a href="https://www.sergiocarballo.es/" target="_blank">SergioCarballo.es</a></p></span>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Os dejo la web donde podeis visualizar el efecto 
http://dev.sergiocarballo.es/excel/testing.php

Comment: Sin saber la estructura de tu tabla, no es posible darte una respuesta concreta. Pero lo que quieres sería básicamente añadir un `WHERE fabricante = '...'` a tu consulta. Edita la pregunta para añadir más información y aclarar cómo está el sistema  y  qué  es lo que quieres obtener, para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Si exacto pero nose como sacar la info con JQuery de un select por ejemplo para que seleccione en el select una opcion que seria el Where (condicion) y lo que busques vaya relacionado al where